# Unable to run bashrc file using ansible

Tags: ansible

Unable to run bashrc file using ansible.

```
 - name: Source Bashrc
   action: shell source /local/apps/actional/.bash_profile
```

is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`source` is a build-in, not command.

Try this:

```
---
- hosts: target-server
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - copy:
        content: export MYVAR=123
        dest: /tmp/source_test
    - shell: /bin/bash -c 'source /tmp/source_test; echo $MYVAR'
```

Keep in mind that you can use sourced environment only within one Ansible task – each task is executed in new shell.